# ¿Cómo hacer que mi formulario de contacto envíe mensajes? Me da error 405 Not Allowed, sin más descripción

Tags: php, formularios

Mi formulario de contacto no me deja enviar mensajes. Me da el error 405 Not Allowed sin mas descripción que ayude a encontrar el error. Aprendí hace muy poco a crear formularios de contacto a través de Youtube y aun no soy capaz de resolver este tipo de errores. Por favor, necesito que alguien me eche una mano.

**CÓDIGO HTML DEL FORMULARIO:**

```html
<form action="enviar.php" method="POST">
  <label for="Nombre">Nombre:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="name" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre">

  <label for="Email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Escribe tu Email">

  <label for="Mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
  <textarea type="text" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje"></textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

**CÓDIGO PHP DEL FORMULARIO (Nombre del archivo:enviar.php):**

```html
<?php
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

    
    $para = "indiajoyas@hotmail.com";
    $asunto = "Nuevo mensaje de la web";
    
    $mensaje="
             De: ".$nombre."
             Mensaje: ".$mensaje."
             Email: ".$email."
             ";

    mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);
    header("location:index.html");
?>
```

**CÓDIGO CSS DEL FORMULARIO (Por si ayuda):**

```css
form{
    width:70%;
    padding:1.25rem;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:7rem;
    margin-bottom:8rem;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

label{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    font-size:0.94rem;
    padding:1.25rem;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}

textarea{
    min-height:9.38rem;
    max-height:18.75rem;
    resize:vertical;
    margin-bottom:1.25rem;
}

input, textarea{
    width:100%;
    border:0.06rem solid #000;
    padding:1.25rem;
    font-size:0.87rem;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:0.94rem;
    border:none;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Significa que el método POST no está permitido en ese recurso. ¿Es un servidor remoto? Deberás revisar la configuración de dicho servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo he intentado con GET y tampoco funciona. Tengo el proyecto en Github.

Comment: Revisa [este enlace](https://www.ionos.mx/digitalguide/hosting/cuestiones-tecnicas/el-error-405-que-es-y-como-solucionarlo/), te explica el por qué del error 405, a ver si así consigues resolver tu problema.

Comment: Tienes que desbloquear los métodos HTTP que quieras utilizar, eso depende del servidor (bajo qué software está corriendo) y de los privilegios que tengas. Si es tu propio servidor podrás desbloquearlos, si es un alojamiento compartido probablemente tengas que contactar con el soporte técnico del alojador.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano por el esfuerzo. Pero sin una respuesta más clara no puedo hacer nada para solucionar el problema. De momento, investigando he leído que Github no procesa archivos php. Si eso es cierto tendría que olvidarme del archivo php que he creado para validar mi formulario de contacto. Seguiré investigando a ver si me confirman que Github no procesa archivos php.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta para explicar el contexto? No podrás procesar un archivo `.php` alojado en Github desde otro servidor, sería harto peligroso. Los archivos `.php` generalmente están en el servidor que los procesa. Por poner un ejemplo, si tienes una página web alojada en dominio cualquiera, los archivos `.php` de esa página deben estar en el servidor de tu dominio, no en Github. Desde Github podrías tomar a lo sumo archivos `.txt`, archivos `.json` u otros, pero no `.php` que tienen una potencia de ejecución enorme en el servidor. Por favor explica el contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resuelto:

He creado un formulario de contacto en formspree.io con código Html. Lo he copiado y pegado en mi proyecto. Le he aplicado código CSS y listo para funcionar en mi sitio web alojado en Github sin necesidad de código Php.